# Magento Partial Payment / Invoice / Refund

Tags: invoice

I need to know what kind of partial things are possible in Magento ?

Like we say **Partial Payment / Partial Invoice / Partial Refund**

If any of the above is possible then how can I implement it ?

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 3):

Creating Patial Invoice and Partial Refund is possible in Magento. During development payment method you should extend it from `Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract`.

This class has properties `$_canCapturePartial` and `$_canRefundInvoicePartial`.

By default they are false. Redefine them in your payment method and set to true.

Now in backend you will have ability to create partial Invoice and Refund. From developer point of view will be called the same funtions of your method `capture` and `refund`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Could you pls let me know after setting them to true where can I see the partial buttons ? And is Partial Payment also possible ?

Comment: You can find them in admin order edit page.
What do you mean under `Partial Payment`?

Comment: $_canCapturePartial and $_canRefundInvoicePartial are set to true and nothing is changed. Still I am not able to create or select any option from edit order which allows me to build partial invoice.Please guide.

Comment: During creating invoice can you edit items amount?

Comment: Under Items to Invoice tab, I can just edit 'Qty to Invoice' field and not the amount anywhere

Comment: But changing qty of the product and pressing "update qty" button will update the amount. That is partial invoice functionality. Magento Partial invoice does not allow to change invoice amount directly and that is logically.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13434/discussion-between-mark-and-oleksii-svarychevskyi)

Comment: I am using Mage ver 1.8. Placed an order with two items and updated qty of one of items to 0 and created invoice ? Without setting $_canCapturePartial and $_canRefundInvoicePartial to true..How is this working ?

Comment: The main point here is that `$_canCapture` should also be set to true.

Comment: $_canCapture is set to false.

Comment: It means that during capture magento creates offline invoice. Without sending any request to payment method. In this case the value of $_canCapturePartial is ignored because you can always create partial invoice offline.